# Draw2d: Containing RectangleFigure will sometimes cuts off text when zoomed. (Pictures included)

Tags: word-wrap, zooming, draw2d

In my program I have a bunch of RectangleFigures where each figure holds text.  The text is held in a TextFlow which is held by FlowPage to allow word wrapping.  RectangleFigure then uses getPrefferedSize() to make itself just big enough to hold it's text (using a fixed width).

These RectangleFigures are held by a ScalableLayeredPane.  The problem rises when I try to zoom by calling setScale().  Most of the time it works fine but occasionally the ends of the text will be cut off.  If I zoom again the figure will correct itself.  I should also say that I have tested my program using Figure instead of RectangleFigure with the same result.

Has anyone dealt with this bug before and can shed some light on why this is happening and/or know of any workarounds?

I havn't included any code because this is a rather large program and relevant chunks of code are spread out.  But if you would like to see the code let me know and I will try piecing it together.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was holding the text inside a Figure and that was the Figure I was calling getPrefferedSize() on.  But I then put that Figure(lets call it textFigure) inside a second Figure(called containerFigure).  I was essentially doing the equivalent of containerFigure.setSize(textFigure.getPrefferedSize()).

You're probably wondering why I was doing that.  Well originally I planned on having containerFigure hold multiple things instead of just textFigure.  I ended up coding it differently but forgot about the unnecessary extra layer.

So even though containerFigure was technically the size it needed to be scaling caused problems.  But when I removed containerFigure and started placing textFigure directly on the screen this bug was fixed.

This is a fairly specific error on my part so I don't know how much help this will be to others.  To make it more broad if you're having some kind of sizing issue just check to see how the size of parent Figures are being set.  Using sizes from child Figures might be incorrect and/or causing problems.